# Is there a way to create a data structure that can store integer, float, boolean and string data internally in a PDF document?

Tags: object, pdf, data-structures, dataset, pdf-generation

I am doing a project and need to store small datasets internally in PDF documents and after store, retrieve these data. The data can be integers, float, booleans and strings, and I need to know if it is possible to create an object which can store these type of data (something similar to an Array List in Java) and how can I after that retrieve the data (identification of these objects is what I have the most doubts about).

If you have any answer I would be very grateful if you share it!

Comment: Use a file attachment and store data in an XML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to work with PDF, you should have a look at its specification ISO 32000.

Already part 1 in section 7.3 defines among other PDF object types **Boolean**, **Numeric** (both integer and real), **String**, and **Array** objects.

Furthermore, it says in Annex E that *a conforming writer may also add keys to any PDF object that is implemented as a dictionary, except the file trailer dictionary* and then describes a way to prevent key name collisions in such dictionaries.

So what you could do is add a custom key (with a prefix you have to register) to the PDF **Catalog** the value of which is your array (or whatever structure you want to have there), e.g.

```cos
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
   /Pages 2 0 R
   /PageMode /UseOutlines
   /Outlines 3 0 R
   /MKLx_SO_Felipe [1.2 False 17 (A String)]
>>
endobj
```

To add such an entry and to retrieve it again later, you should use an existing, general purpose PDF library for your programming language and runtime. Writing such a thing oneself can turn out to be more complicated than desired.

---

Alternatively you can store your data in a file with a format of your choice (XML, JSON, ..., you name it) and embed that file in the PDF, either as a file attachment as proposed by Kevin Brown in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66844770/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-data-structure-that-can-store-integer-float-boolean#comment118164317_66844770) or as an arbitrary PDF stream referenced from a custom name in some dictionary.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, just one more question: what do you think about Java to process the store and retrieve of this datasets in PDF documents?

Comment: *"what do you think about Java to process the store and retrieve of this datasets in PDF documents?"* - There are a number of general purpose Java PDF libraries you could use for that task, for example iText and PDFBox.

Comment: Hello again, I have one more question: after reading the Annex E, as you said before, it refers to a Name Registry for private data, is it possible not to register the key of the objects within the dictionary? I say this because I find it a bit tricky and maybe for a small project it might be easier to do it without registration.

Comment: Registration of a prefix is trivial, see https://github.com/adobe/pdf-names-list - but of course you can try without, but if you happen to choose a name in someone else's namespace or a first class name, the registered/official interpretation will always come first.